# Owl Carousel: Javascript won't load. Shopify Issue or Code Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify, owl-carousel

Trying to get my owl carousel to work for me in shopify. Could you take a look at my code and see if anything looks off to you?

I think I've implemented it the to T but it won't seem to fire. Any suggestions would be great!

CSS Styles

```
{{ 'owl.theme.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'owl.carousel.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

JS Files

```
{{ 'owl.carousel.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Slider HTML

```
{% if collection.handle contains "tee" %}

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#heroSlider").owlCarousel({

    navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem:true

    // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
    // items : 1, 
    // itemsDesktop : false,
    // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
    // itemsTablet: false,
    // itemsMobile : false
});
});
 </script>

<div id="heroSlider" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0246/3225/files/2girlsinTSHIRT.jpg?2088744847513182869" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0246/3225/files/2girlsinTSHIRT.jpg?2088744847513182869" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0246/3225/files/2girlsinTSHIRT.jpg?2088744847513182869" /></div>
</div>


{% endif %}
```

Seems to be an issue with the jQuery.

```
When I have 
  {{ 'jquery-1.10.2.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'owl.carousel.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

I can at least see the images. Without one or they other, they disappear.

Comment: So I don't think this is best practice.. But by using the double jQuery links and adding the Javascript from one of the examples I seem to have had a change of luck. Not sure what the issue is with the jQuery so i'll leave this open incase anyone can comment on that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a problem with `jQuery.noConflict()`. You're calling it, then trying to run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#heroSlider").owlCarousel({
    // ...
  });  
});
```

Later, you're restoring `$` with `$ = jQuery;`, but it's too late.

Use `jQuery(document).ready(function() {...` instead

Comment: This would make sense, thank you! I've made the changes you've introduced and while it was working before I know this is better practice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your including owl carousel before jquery. Try

```
{{ 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'owl.carousel.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately this did not fix the issue.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the jQuery. When I load two versions of jQuery, {{ 'jquery-1.10.2.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }} and {{ 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }} I can see the images stacked. Removing one or the other, removes the images.

Comment: @Alan You're probably seeing the images stacked because you're breaking the JS and seeing the default css. That wouldn't mean you were on the right track.

Comment: @ClaytonLeis As always I appreciate any input people are willing to give me but you're wrong. The CSS hides the images by default, seeing them means that the JS was kicking over and removing that style as it should. I have since fixed the problem if you read my comments above. Still don't know why I need both versions of jQuery but it may be some compatibility issue.

Comment: This is does not work me, this page has partially helped, instead of  $(document).ready(function() { wouild you chage it to this: jQuery(document).ready(function() {... or this $jQuery(document).ready(function() {...

Answer (score 0):

Dude this now works, get rid of the JS

```
{{ 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

And put this under the jQuery links in the header, Shopify already has JQuery, you do not need more Jquery, as it will disable the carousel. So you just need the owl carousel js, shopify does the rest. I found this out the hard way.

```
{{ 'owl.carousel.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

You will get the result you need.

Here is the question i raised as well.

[Shopify Carousels, Owl, slider, ResponsiveSlides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401375/shopify-carousels-owl-slider-responsiveslides)

Answer (score 0):

As [stated at the official Github page for Owl Carousel](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1925), this happens because the jQuery is being loaded after the library.

You simply need to wait for jQuery to load. Do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            ...
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

and everything should work just fine.