# Shopify Carousels, Owl, slider, ResponsiveSlides

Tags: shopify, owl-carousel

Please can someone help I have tried to implement 3 kinds of carousels and nothing is working:

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

http://slidesjs.com/

http://responsiveslides.com/

Nothing works, I have added the JS and CSS like this:

```
 <!-- CSS ================================================== -->
  {{ 'timber.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'theme.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'index.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'owl.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'scoot-baby.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}



   <!-- JS ================================================== -->
  {{ 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'owl.carousel.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Then the html with the JS on the home page like this:

```
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

      <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1334/7245/t/1/assets/fullimage1.jpg?15259394755119812233" alt="The Last of us"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1334/7245/t/1/assets/fullimage2.jpg?15259394755119812233" alt="GTA V"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1334/7245/t/1/assets/fullimage3.jpg?15259394755119812233" alt="Mirror Edge"></div>

    </div>

  <style>
    #owl-demo .item img{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
      jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true,
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem : true

      // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
      // items : 1,
      // itemsDesktop : false,
      // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      // itemsTablet: false,
      // itemsMobile : false

      });
    });
    </script>
```

Nothing works nothing, i found this on stackoverflow

[Owl Carousel: Javascript won't load. Shopify Issue or Code Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359498/owl-carousel-javascript-wont-load-shopify-issue-or-code-issue)

Nothing works so i found this on the shopify forum

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-to-use-owl-carousel-for-blog-355756

Nothing works, please can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery uses the `$` sign as a shortcut for jQuery.

What if other JavaScript frameworks (Angular, Backbone, etc) also use the `$` sign as a shortcut? If two different frameworks are using the same shortcut, one of them might stop working.

The jQuery team have already thought about this, and implemented the `noConflict()` method. The `noConflict()` method releases the hold on the `$` shortcut identifier, so that other scripts can use it.

You can of course still use jQuery, simply by writing the full name instead of the shortcut.

So either Remove `jQuery.noConflict();`from your JavaScript. Or if you really need to use it, change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y2r2sp5v/)

Comment: Thanks @NickTheWrench just did that but it doesn't work

Comment: I just copied your exact code into the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2r2sp5v/) and it works. So I'm not sure what else to say unless you can provide more details. Are you sure that jQuery and owl.carousel.js are loading properly on the page?

Comment: Yep you did and it worked fine but in shopify i don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery and owl.carousel.js are loading properly on the page?

Comment: I dont know how to find out, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122941/discussion-between-nickythewrench-and-jelly46).